# Python Add data from array to prettytable via column

Tags: python, python-3.x, prettytable

I created an array full of number. I want to add data from the array to the prettytable basically using add_columns

```
number=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.....,100]
```

I want the output of the pretty table to be like this below

```
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| Number  |1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | .....                  |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
```

My code is shown below.

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = PrettyTable()
x.add_column(["number", print(number)])
print(x)
```

When I run the python script, it generated an error

> TypeError: add_column() missing 1 required positional argument: 'column'

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use add raw like this and if
you need to add 'number' as text you should added in the list

```
number=['number',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

from prettytable import PrettyTable
x = PrettyTable()
x.add_row(number)
print(x)
```

OUTPUT:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4 | Field 5 | Field 6 | Field 7 | Field 8 | Field 9 | Field 10 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
|  number |    1    |    2    |    3    |    4    |    5    |    6    |    7    |    8    |    9     |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove the Header field? I am referring to the Field 1, Field 2, Field 3

Comment: as I know you can't